# Trouble creating files php

Tags: php, file, fopen

I already tried all ways that i know:

```
<?php
   DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile($filename);
?>
```

,

```
<?php 
    fopen(); //I tried all the options and modes.
    fwrite();
    fclose();
?>
```

and

```
<?php
   file_put_contents($filename, $data);
?>
```

What disquiets me is that all three ways returns me the written bytes, as if the file had been created, but when i search for the file, it simply does not exists.

Have anyone some idea?

Actual codes:

-fopen attempt:

```
<?php$
   $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/view/pages/' . $pageName . '.html';
   file = fopen($filename, 'x');
   $save = fwrite($file, $this->topicData['html']);
   fclose($file);
   if($save) return 1;
   else return "Error";
?>
```

-saveHTMLFile attempt:

```
<?php
   $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/view/pages/' . $pageName . '.html';
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($this->topicData['html']);
   if ($doc->saveHTMLFile($filename)) return 1;
   else return "Error";
?>
```

-file_put_contents attempt:

```
<?php
   $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/view/pages/' . $newPage . '.html';
   if(file_put_contents($filename, $this->topicData['html'])) return 1;
   else return 'Error';
?>
```

All of them returns 1, but no file is truly created.

Comment: Did you use an absolute or relative path?

Comment: I used abolute path. I will post the code.

Comment: I used that path: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']./dir/file.html

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

The problem was in another part of the code which treats the name of the file that will be created. So, it was overwriting files and i wasn't able to find the file with the name that i was searching by.

But thank you all, it's solved.